# curl works on Windows 7 but not on CentOS

Tags: php, linux, curl

On Windows works perfectly but not on Linux.

Got this error:

"curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer"

```
$url = 'some_url';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/json"
  )
));

$response = curl_exec( $curl );
$err = curl_error( $curl );

curl_close( $curl );
```

Is there some special setting for this?

Turned off firewall but same error. Any idea what to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with ssl version.

with "CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 1" works fine

As I found:

- SSLv2 is disabled by default since 7.18.1. Other SSL versions availability may vary depending on which backend libcurl has been built to use.
- SSLv3 is disabled by default since 7.39.0.

My version of curl on Linux is 7.29.0 (on Windows 7.55.1) so by default he tried with sslv3 and that cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a firewall issue, if you are using a VMware, make sure the firewall on the antivirus is turned off also please check the firewall rule of server.

or you can check the URL like i tried using https://example.net - but they ensure 'www.' - so when i switched to https://www.example.net everything seems to work perfectly for me.Proper request was sent.